Some comments were deleted with obvious bias
Under my question Is the term "terrorism" defined in international law?, in the comments I was accused of both anti-semitism and bias against Israel. Interestingly, my responses were all deleted, yet the comments containing the accusations remain there. I don't know who can delete comments and who cannot. My guess is that only the moderators are able to do that. I find this behavior both biased and insulting. This site needs moderators who can act impartially and respectfully. When you delete comments in this way, at least notify the people involved somehow, by a comment or by website notification, if possible.

I don't see any comments on the question accusing you of "anti-semitism and bias against Israel", so it seems they have in fact been deleted now.

@F1Krazy, That's correct. They were deleted after I wrote here. But the moderator also edited ( =censored ) my post heavily, as described in the answer below. I think this site is pro-Israel, which is not strange, as it is originated in western countries. But it's difficult to find truth in a biased environment.

Let me give just an example: There is a post on this site asking why some countries haven't called Iran a terrorist state. Can you even imagine such post remain intact on this site about Israel?

TBH sometimes it's best to keep the motivation for a Q just for yourself. Making it public sometimes helps and sometimes it doesn't, especially if your motivation involves an unpopular opinion.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, In the 'real' life I have to behave as you said. But on the internet, I'm a free person, more or less. If people somewhere don't like my posts or I don't like their behavior, I simply find another place.

I removed your responses, and the responses to it, and the responses to the responses, and the responses to the responses to the responses etc. because they were not constructive. Remember the purpose of comments on stack exchange. The purpose of comments is to point out flaws in the content they are posted on. Not to engage in lengthy debates. Culling debates that go on for too long is standard practice on all of Stack Exchange.
I left the original comments, because they did what they are supposed to be doing: Pointing out flaws in the content.
However, it doesn't seem like you want to react to this criticism yourself by editing the question. So I now did what every user with 1000+ reputation can do and improved the question to remove the questionable section. It wasn't necessary to understand what the question is asking. It was only making a political point and was only causing controversy. Politics Stack Exchange is not a platform for political activism and not a discussion forum either. So it didn't belong.
After that, the comments pointing out the bias no longer apply, so I removed them as well.

More insulting and biased behavior. I leave this site.

People usually do not express their real motives. For example, there are many posts on this site calling Iran terrorist. I'm not saying Iran has a good government. I'm saying the moderators aren't impartial.

Quote: "it doesn't seem like you want to react to this criticism yourself by editing the question. So I now did."  I don't have to react to all criticisms. Not all criticisms are valid.

Well, you could also have cleaned up the accepted answer, which also had suggestions for improvement which were just as ignored.  But, as you say, this can easily be done by others, so I have done just that.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The 'suggestion' for the OP [that you deleted] in that answer were literally for them to 'give up': "I suspect what you want is some set of words to prove a point...  . So if you just want to prove a point - please give up now."
